# Does Juniper set a control word on VPLS pseudowires

Tags: juniper, mpls, juniper-mx, vpls

At the RIPE conference the was a talk about how MAC addresses starting with a 4or 6 may suffer from decreased performance because MPLS routers misinterpret the Ethernet packets as an IPv4/6 packet when load balancing over multiple links.

[Presentation is here](https://ripe66.ripe.net/presentations/141-RIPE66_Understanding_MPLS_Hashing-Snijders.pdf)

One workaround would be to insert additional fields to prevent misinterpretation of the packets. Control words do the trick. Now, I know that control words are enabled on l2vpn connections on juniper by default, but I can't find any information regarding VPLS.

Does anyone know if control words are sent when using VPLS on juniper by default or if we can enable them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

negotiation of the control-word between the BGP VPLS PE routers is added in Juniper MX series starting from [Junos 14.1](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.1/topics/task/configuration/vpls-bgp-control-word-configuring.html). so only BGP-signaled VPLS.

BR

Answer (score 6):

I don't know for sure, but

`set routing-instances red instance-type vpls protocols vpls control-word`

commits for me on *12.3R2.5*

and this is mentioned [here](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.2/information-products/topic-collections/release-notes/12.2/index.html?topic-66803.html):

> On MX Series routers with the Channelized OC3/STM1 (Multi-Rate)
>   Circuit Emulation MIC with SFP, Junos OS substantially supports RFC
>   4385, Pseudowire Emulation Edge-to-Edge (PWE3) Control Word for Use
>   over an MPLS PSN